# show and hide div that is in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

When I click on the image or text I want to hide this current div and show another  div which also use ng-repeat

this code html to show primary image with text :

```
<div class="img-container" ng-repeat="sign in signs.List">
   <img class="animated" ng-src="{{sign.animated_src}}" width="200" height="150" />

<div>{{sign.texte}}</div>
</div>
```

For example I have 4 image with text (number, alphat, ...)

click in text number => show this div that contains this and hide the other

```
<div class = "img-container" ng-repeat = "sign in signs.number">
    <Img class = "animated" ng-src = "{{sign.animated_src}}" width = "200" height = "150"/>
<div> {{sign.texte}} </ div>
</div>
```

click in  alphat => show this div that contains this and hide the other

```
<div class = "img-container" ng-repeat = "sign in signs.alphat">
    <Img class = "animated" ng-src = "{{sign.animated_src}}" width = "200" height = "150"/>
<div> {{sign.texte}} </ div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understand right..

HTML

```
<div class="img-container" ng-repeat="sign in signs.list">
    <img class="animated" ng-src="{{sign.animated_src}}" 
             width="200" height="150" 
             ng-click="filterList(sign.texte)" />
    <div ng-click="filterList(sign.texte)">{{sign.texte}}</div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$scope.filterList = function(char){
        if(typeof char === typeof 0){
        $scope.signs.list = $scope.signs.number;
    }
    else{
        $scope.signs.list = $scope.signs.alpha;
    }
};

$scope.signs = {
  list: ["A", 1, "B", 2, "C", 3],
  number: [1, 2, 3],
  alpha: ["A", "B", "C"]
};
```

Working fiddle ==> https://jsfiddle.net/k19g6vsb/

Comment: But each text has div are corresponding
How can i know what text i have to select it to show its div

Comment: I honestly don't understand...can you post the complete HTML?

Comment: I explained more please look at it

Comment: Can you check now please?

Comment: no this code html to show primary image with text :

<div class="img-container" ng-repeat="sign in signs.List">
   <img class="animated" ng-src="{{sign.animated_src}}" width="200" height="150" />

<div>{{sign.texte}}</div>
</div>

Comment: and click in text number => show div and hide the other

Comment: Ok, your english is terrible :) But seriously now I understand...wait a sec...I'm creating a fiddle

Comment: To be sure: You want the list of images and text, which are alpha and numbers. When the user clicks number, only numbers are shown and alpha are hidden. But how to reset??

Comment: Reset when user returns to the main list which are (number, alphat)

Comment: Yes, but you set no button to do that!! Anyway check this ==> https://jsfiddle.net/k19g6vsb/

Comment: now i need only show and hide div according to choice of text

Answer (score 0):

use the `ng-show` and `ng-hide` directives

```
<div ng-hide="showItem" class="img-container" ng-repeat="sign in signs.List">
   <img class="animated" ng-src="{{sign.animated_src}}" width="200" height="150" ng-click="showItem = !showItem" />
</div>
<div ng-show="showItem" class="img-container" ng-repeat="sign in signs.List">
   <img class="animated" ng-src="{{sign.animated_src}}" width="200" height="150" ng-click="showItem = !showItem" />
</div>
</div>
<div ng-init="showThis = true" ng-click="showItem = !showItem"> {{sign.texte}}</div>
```

Comment: But each text has div are corresponding
How can i know what text i have to select it to show its div

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is the code sample please check
```

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
 
  $scope.toggle = true;
    $scope.toggleFilter = function() {
      this.toggle = !this.toggle
    }
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 /**** Ignore This ***/
    var testDATA = {
      name : "name",
      name2: "name2"
    }
    var list = [];
    for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
      testDATA.name = angular.copy("name"+i);
      
      list.push(testDATA);
    }
    console.log("test",list);
  $scope.list = list;
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.20/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.20"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div>
      <p ng-repeat="obj in list track by $index">
        <span ng-hide="toggle">{{obj.name}}</span>
        <span ng-show="toggle">{{obj.name2}}</span>
        <span>
          <input type="button" value="toggle" ng-click="toggleFilter();">
        </span>
      </p>
      
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Here is the plunker for this :[PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/7NCB3yGp4MrlRbjL9tZ5?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Angular Ajax with PHP</title>
</head>
<body>

<h2>The form</h2>

<div  ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mainController">


<div class="img-container" ng-repeat="sign in signs.List">
    <div ng-show="show == $index">
       <img class="animated" ng-src="{{sign.src}}" ng-click="increment()" width="200" height="150" />
       <div>{{sign.text}}</div>
    </div>
</div>


</div>



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>

var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller('mainController',function($scope){
  $scope.show = 0;
  $scope.signs = {};
  $scope.signs.List = [];
  $scope.signs.List.push({src:"img1.jpg",text:"Text 1"});
  $scope.signs.List.push({src:"img2.jpg",text:"Text 2"});

  $scope.increment = function() {
    $scope.show = $scope.show + 1;
    if ($scope.show >= $scope.signs.List.length) {

            $scope.show = 0;
    }
  }

});
</script>


</body>
</html>
```